# I do not understand how to implement the user interface on Racket

Tags: user-interface, scheme, racket

Began picking GUI in Racket and immediately interjected with tabs. That's where butted (ask for the code not much to find fault, I just started to learn Racket):

```
#lang racket/gui 
(define my-settings-hash (make-hash))
(define my-settings-hash "label" "Test")
(define my-settings-hash "width" 300)
(define my-settings-hash "height" 300)
(define my-tabs-list (list "Tab 0"
                           "Tab 1"
                           "Tab 2"))
(define root-wnd (new frame% [label (hash-ref my-settibgs-hash "label")]
                             [width (hash-ref my-settings-hash "width")]
                             [height (hash-ref my-settings-hash "height"]))
(define tab-panel (new tab-panel%
                             (parent root-wnd)
                             (choices my-tabs-list)
                             (callback
                               (lambda (tp e)
                                (case (send tp get-selection)
                                 ((0) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list a-panel))))
                                 ((1) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list b-panel))))
                                 ((2) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list a-panel)))))))))
(define a-panel (new panel%
                 (parent tab-panel)
                 (label "A-panel")))
(define b-panel (new panel%
                 (parent tab-panel)
                  (label "b-panel")))
(send frame show #t)
```

(sorry, if there is extra brackets). Here is the problem - when the program is started in the main window of the two panels, but only after the switch is lost, and one is left alone. Where I blunt? I would be grateful if you would give a correction or a working example (but please with the decision of "head", because until very badly know racket and I can not understand, more or less complex). Thank you in advance!

Comment: "sorry if there is extra brackets" : why not cut-and-paste the exact code you are using, instead of apologizing for transcription errors  (which there are indeed) that make it difficult for people to duplicate your experiment?

Answer (score 7):

### Mistakes in the comprehension of Racket language

You have many more mistakes in your code than just "extra brackets."  Your sample code, which does not run at all for me, indicates that you do not have enough basic proficiency in Racket itself to make very efficient progress working on developing a GUI in it.  An example of such a mistake is the line:

```lisp
 (define my-settings-hash "label" "Test")`
```

The `define` form cannot be formed this way; it does not sense in Racket (or Scheme) to say

```
(define N A B)
```

if `N` is merely an identifier.

### Mistakes in Development Methodology

You should develop your code in DrRacket; that will help you correct a lot of the errors you have made in your code.  Since you have a `#lang` directive at the top of your code, you should be able to get started immediately in DrRacket itself.

Another example of a mistake that DrRacket would easily catch: the incorrectly spelled identifier `my-settibgs-hash`.

As for your actual question of how to implement tabs, as you asked, you should read the documentation for the `tab-panel%` class itself.  DrRacket has an integrated Help Desk, so you can right-click on an identifier like `tab-panel%` and one of the menu options provided is "View documentation for tab-panel% from racket/gui/base, racket/gui"; clicking that takes you to a local copy of the [documentation web page](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/tab-panel_.html) for that class.

### Mistakes in the use of the tab-panel% interface

After reading the documentation for `tab-panel%`, note in particular that `tab-panel%` does not have a `label` argument, at least not in version 5.3.2 (which is new, but I suspect this interface has not changed significantly in a while).  I do not know what you are trying to do there, but I suspect you are trying to get some sort of text to show up inside the panel.  There are a couple different options for creating text in Racket; the simplest one is probably `message%`.  (I recommend browsing the [whole widget gallery](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Widget_Gallery.html) though, since other widgets there may be a better match for what you want.)

### Example fixed code

Here is my revised version of your code, cut-and-pasted from my running DrRacket.  I have tried to remain faithful to as much of your original code as I can (I assume you must have transcribed it from somewhere, given the basic mistakes that were present in the transcription; it would have been good of you to provide a link to that original source).

```
#lang racket/gui 

(define my-settings-hash (make-hash))
(hash-set! my-settings-hash "label" "Test")
(hash-set! my-settings-hash "width" 300)
(hash-set! my-settings-hash "height" 300)
(define my-tabs-list (list "Tab 0"
                           "Tab 1"
                           "Tab 2"))
(define root-wnd (new frame% [label (hash-ref my-settings-hash "label")]
                             [width (hash-ref my-settings-hash "width")]
                             [height (hash-ref my-settings-hash "height")]))
(define tab-panel (new tab-panel%
                             (parent root-wnd)
                             (choices my-tabs-list)
                             (callback
                               (lambda (tp e)
                                (case (send tp get-selection)
                                 ((0) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list a-panel))))
                                 ((1) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list b-panel))))
                                 ((2) (send tp change-children (lambda (children)
                                                                 (list a-panel)))))))))
(define a-panel (new panel% (parent tab-panel)))
(define a-text (new message% (parent a-panel) (label "A-panel")))
(define b-panel (new panel% (parent tab-panel)))
(define b-text (new message% (parent b-panel) (label "b-panel")))

(send root-wnd show #t)
```